# Inserting data into a table with new and old data from another two tables

Tags: sql

I have a table name `Queue_info` with structure as

```
Queue_Id number(10)
Movie_Id number(10)
User_Id Varchar2(20)
Status Varchar2(20)
Reserved_date date
```

I have two other tables named `Movie_info` having a many columns including `movie_Id` and `User_info` having many columns including `User_Id`.

In the first table `movie_id, user_id` is foreign key from `movie_info(movie_id)` and `user_info(User_id)`.

My problem is that if I insert any value either in the `Movie_info` or `User_info`, the `Queue_info` table should be updated as new entry for every user or for every movie

For example 
If insertion in `Movie_info` as new movie then `queue_info` should be updated as for every user the status of that new movie is awaiting.

Comment: Why do you want to update every user with a new movie, automatically? Which database are using?

Answer (score 0):

use from triggers. by using triggers you can update all related tables to your table. for example if 1 row inserted in to table 1, 1 row insert in to table 2 too.

Answer (score 0):

Some notes first:

- I really like that you have a standardized way to name tables and fields. I would use `Queue` instead of `Queue_info`, `Movie` instead of `Movie_info`, etc..., as all tables have information - don't they? - and we all know that. I'd also choose `MovieId` instead of `Movie_Id`, `ReservedDate` instead of `Resedrved_date` but that's a matter of personal taste (allergy to underscores).
  What I wanted to stress is that choosing one way for naming and keeping it is very good.
- What I don't like is that while your structure seems normalized, you use `Varchar` type for the `User_id` Key. Primary (and Foreign) Keys are best if they are small in size and with constant size. This mainly helps in keeping index sizes small (so more efficient) and secondly because the keys are the only values stored repeatedly in the db (so it helps keeping db size small).

---

Now, to your question, do you really need this? I mean, you may end up having in your database thousands of movies and users. Do you want to add a thousand rows in the `Queue` table whenever a new movie is inserted? Or another thousand rows when a new user is registered? Or 50 thousand rows when a new list with 50 new movies arrives (and is inserted in the db)?

With 10K movies and 2K users, you'll have a 20M rows table. There is no problem with a table of that size, and one or more triggers will serve your need. What happens if you have 100K movies and 50K users though? A 5G rows table. You can deal with that too, but perhaps you can just keep in that table only the movies that a user is interested in (or has borrowed or has seen, whatever the purpose of the db is). And if you want to have a list of movies that a certain user has not yet been interested in, check for those `Movie_Id` that do not exist in the table. with something like this:

```
SELECT
    Movie_Id, Movie_Title
FROM 
    Movie_info AS m
WHERE 
    NOT EXISTS
      ( SELECT *
        FROM Queue_info AS q
        WHERE q.Movie_Id = m.Movie_Id
          AND q.User_Id = @UserId
      )
```